# Как лучше реализовать такую фигуру?

Tags: html, css

Как лучше реализовать такой блок? На заднем фоне картинка. А сверху блок с размытием с такой же формой как картинка? Пробовал через transform matrix но текст который я потом добавил также трансформировался?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Наверное помог вам ^-^
Вот вам мой код

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.test {
  width: min(480px, 100%);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  background-image: url('https://images8.alphacoders.com/632/thumb-1920-632051.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.test-logo {
  width: calc(100% - 25px);
  text-align: center;
}

.test-logo > img {
  width: 100%;
}

.test-text {
  position: relative;
  font-family: consolas;
  padding: 64px 32px 32px 32px;
  color: #FFF;
  z-index: 99;
}

.test-title {
  color: #FFA500;
  font-size: 42px;
}

.btn {
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  padding: 24px 0;
  font-size: 32px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 16px 0;
  font-family: consolas;
  transition: .25s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  color: red;
}

.btn-primary {
  background-color: #FFA500;
  color: #FFF;
}

.btn-second {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF;
}

.test-text:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: url('https://images8.alphacoders.com/632/thumb-1920-632051.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  filter: blur(25px);
  clip-path: polygon(0 10%, 100% 0, 100% 80%, 0% 90%);
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="test-logo">
    <img src="https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/61a5576f-81c3-44fb-a4c1-8e226e641b42/d4687x6-16bdfe22-e480-4887-8cfd-9e0671b808ee.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7InBhdGgiOiJcL2ZcLzYxYTU1NzZmLTgxYzMtNDRmYi1hNGMxLThlMjI2ZTY0MWI0MlwvZDQ2ODd4Ni0xNmJkZmUyMi1lNDgwLTQ4ODctOGNmZC05ZTA2NzFiODA4ZWUucG5nIn1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmZpbGUuZG93bmxvYWQiXX0.gs92cfSYVUzqgY4mzExz5-vmnz1dHHjW73TBhwlLNu0">
  </div>
  <div class="test-text">
    <h1 class="test-title">Доставка что-то там ...</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
    <div class="test-buttons">
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Рассчитать</button>
      <button class="btn btn-second">Найти</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```